# Allow kubernetes storageclass resturl HTTPS with self-signed certificate

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, openssl, glusterfs

I'm currently trying to setup GlusterFS integration for a Kubernetes cluster. Volume provisioning is done with Heketi.

GlusterFS-cluster has a pool of 3 VMs
1st node has Heketi server and client configured. Heketi API is secured with a self-signed certificate OpenSSL and can be accessed.

e.g. curl https://heketinodeip:8080/hello -k
returns the expected response.

StorageClass definition sets the "resturl" to Heketi API https://heketinodeip:8080

When storageclass was created successfully and I try to create a PVC, this fails:

"x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"

This is expected, as ususally one has to allow this insecure HTTPS-connection or explicitly import the issuer CA (e.g. a file simply containing the pem-String)

But: How is this done for Kubernetes? How do I allow this insecure connection to Heketi from Kubernetes, allowing insecure self-signed cert HTTPS or where/how do I import a CA?

It is not an DNS/IP problem, this was resolved with correct subjectAltName settings.

(seems that everybody is using Heketi, and it seems to be still a standard usecase for GlusterFS integration, but always without SSL, if connected to Kubernetes)

Thank you!

Comment: How are you signing Heketi certificates? Have you tried signing them with kubernetes CA?

Answer (score 0):

`To skip verification of server cert, caller just need specify InsecureSkipVerify: true.` Refer this github issue for more information (https://github.com/heketi/heketi/issues/1467)

In this page, they have specified a way to use self signed certificate. Not explained thoroughly but still can be useful (https://github.com/gluster/gluster-kubernetes/blob/master/docs/design/tls-security.md#self-signed-keys).

Comment: I found these links too. First one simply supports my expectations, that this is an issue on Kubernetes side. Heketi supports SSL and you can easily configure this.
Second one just provides ideas, what we should think about (I did). And already made me aware of that there will be another self-signed certificate issue on Kubernetes side if a node tries to use a PVC (after volumes will successfully be created) because communication to gluster itself might not work, too. :/